# JSF: How show 'waiting' message?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

i create a contact form, but now i want to show a wait message like 'sending message' for example.

this is what i have done so far:

```
<h:form styleClass="contact">
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}" styleClass="text-input" >
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameMessage" />
    </h:inputText>
    Name (Required)
    <br />
    //..

    <a4j:commandButton value="Do something" action="#{contact.sendMessage}" status="ajaxStatus" />


    <!-- warning messages -->
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="errorMessage" infoClass="infoMessage" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" />
    <h:message id="nameMessage" for="name" errorClass="error" /><br />
</h:form>

<a4j:status id="ajaxStatus" name="ajaxStatus">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <h:graphicImage name="loader.gif" library="images" />
        <h:outputText value="Your message" />
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

**Solution**:
Based in @roel tip:

```
    <h:form styleClass="contact">
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}" styleClass="text-input" >
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameMessage" />
        </h:inputText>
        Nome (Obrigatório)
        //..        
        <a4j:commandButton value="Enviar" action="#{contact.sendMessage}" styleClass="button" status="ajaxStatus" />


        <!-- warning messages -->
<!--         <h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="errorMessage" infoClass="infoMessage" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" /> -->
        <h:message id="nameMessage"    for="name"    errorClass="error" /><br />
        //..
    </h:form>

    <a4j:status name="ajaxStatus">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:graphicImage name="loader.gif" library="images" />
            <h:outputText value="Aguarde um momento ..." />
        </f:facet>
    </a4j:status>
```

But i don't know why is not working.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But to use ypur a4j:status, I believe you either put it outside your form without the name and reference. And no reference in your ajax call

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Do something" action="#{contact.sendMessage}"  />
```

Or leave the name and status reference abut you have to put it inside the form

Comment: thanks by your tip, i put it outside as you suggest and remove the id in my a4:status, works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use a popup panel

```
<rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="busy" width="300" height="150" zindex="10"
        moveable="false" resizeable="false">
<h:outputText value="#{msg.busy_please_wait}" />
</rich:popupPanel>
```

And in the ajax call we use onbegin and oncomplete to show and hide it.

```
<a4j:ajax id="postalCode" event="change" listener="#{myclass.retrievePostalCode}" render="cityGroup address " execute="country houseNumber address city"  oncomplete="#{rich:component('busy')}.hide();" onbegin="#{rich:component('busy')}.show()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever i need process load i do 
Richfaces.showModalPanel('pleaseWaitPanel');

where this is the model panel :

```
<rich:modalPanel id="pleaseWaitpanel" width="yourChoice" height="yourChoice" autosized="true">
<t:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;" >

        <t:div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <t:graphicImage url="look in google for processloading.gif"/>
        </t:div>
    </t:panelGrid>
</rich:modalPanel >
```